# Unable to make a div float in html

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to set one of div postion fixed so that it can be float like right side options.. I want to set set language col below the slider. I am using the flowing css for that

```
postion:fixed
display:block;
z-index:99999;
```

But I am unable to do so. Please tell me how can I do this. Here is the link of website

http://histyletours.com/

Below the slider the language dropdown col I want to make floating like right one

I hope you understand

Experts Please Give me solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to apply position:fixed, and top and right values to the control:

```
.skiptranslate { 
   position: fixed;
   top: 200px;
   right: 15px;
   z-index: 9999;
}
```